# Getting the filenames in specific directory on the client machine

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jsf-2

First I would like to thank this excellent site for all the help for the developers.
I am facing a problem that I need the user to browse to a specific folder on his/her machine then click the submit button.
I like to get all the filenames and types from this folder and read it in a servlet.

Idon't need upload functionality, I need to read the filenames and types in the selected folder.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you tagged this javascript and servlets; the most likely interpretation of that choice is that you want to do this from a webpage.  I don't know if there's anything in stock HTML5 that can support this; it is possible with a signed java applet,(but then you need to put on whatever is the late 1990's equivalent of bellbottoms) and it looks like it should be possible (on Chrome only) using the FileSystemAPI but I don't know for sure.  Could you clarify that doing this through a browser is your intention?

Comment: Yes I want to do it from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with reading the local file system from a web-page within the browser is the sandbox the browser runs in. Normally, you are not able to get out of that sandbox to read the local file system in such a way.
There are a few way around that, for Java you could use a signed applet, or you could use an signed ActiveX control.
Both shouldn't be that difficult, but the Java applet will have a better support all round, since the ActiveX only works on windows.
It's the signing that will become the real problem though. Is this something in a contained environment, or for the actual internet for everyone there to be able to use?
If it's a contained environment, you might be able to pull it off using a self signed certificate. Else you will need a certificate from an actual certificate authority. These can get pretty expensive.

Comment: No it is in an intranet solution. Not on the internet

Comment: Then you should be able to work with a self signed certificate. You then just need people to accept it when the warning pops up